# How to take content part using Regex - preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Content in the `div` inludes new lines, tabulators etc. and probably that's why it doesn't work:

`preg_match('/<div>(.*)</div>/', $i, $matches)`

I tried also `preg_match('/<div>(\n*)(.*)(\n*)</div>/', $i, $matches)`

but still doesn't work. Could you help with that?

Answer (score 2):

Use `preg_match('/<div>(.*)</div>/sm', $i, $matches)`.

For details, what the additional letters mean, read [documentation](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Answer (score 1):

Add the multiline modifier (`m`) to your regex:

```
preg_match('/<div>(.*)</div>/m', $i, $matches);
```

You can read on pattern modifiers on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

While this should work, please don't parse HTML with regexp. There are a lot of information to be found on this page with some searching.

Comment: The DOTALL `/s` modifier in this case, to make `.*` include newlines.

Answer (score 1):

try with the *sm* flags:

```
preg_match('/<div>(.*)<\/div>/sm', $i, $matches);
```